# How do I access all the specific datas of the following table using scrapy?

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to access all the data of the following table elements in the url https://www.jefit.com/exercises/1/
I tried crawling the data using scrapy. But was not able to crawl and some errors came and I was unable to crawl all the data required. Please help me to correct my code to crawl the 'Name' , 'images link' , 'How to perform exercise' and all other data available in the table. 
I am trying out the following code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from myproject.items import getExercise

class MySpider(Spider):
   name = "getExercise"
   allowed_domains = ["www.jefit.com"]
   start_urls = ["https://www.jefit.com/exercises/1/" ]

def parse(self, response):

   item = getExercise()
   item['exerciseName']=response.xpath('//table[@class = "JefitMainTable"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/thead/tr/th/text()').extract()
   return item
```

Comment: are you getting errors other than not getting the data you expect?

Comment: No. It's returning an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `/tbody` by `//` in your XPath.

This is a common issue when checking the XPath only in the browser DOM, as the browser puts `tbody` elements inside tables automatically.

It's often a good idea to try out the XPath expressions in the scrapy shell:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.jefit.com/exercises/1/
>>> response.xpath('//table[@class = "JefitMainTable"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/thead/tr/th/text()').extract()
[]
>>> response.xpath('//table[@class = "JefitMainTable"]//tr/td[2]/table[2]/thead/tr/th/text()').extract()
[u'Band Cross Over']
```